# IE8 ul menu styling problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, styling

I have a menu using an UL, as usual it works finr in FFX but not in IE. I've tried a few things but can't get any good results. Anyone have any ideas or pointers?

please see the attached code and image. If you look closely you can see the bullet points(black) on the left hand side. Where as in firefox a lovely menu is displayed....correctly! :)

Merry Xmas!!!

L

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't find any code here, can you upload it at pastebin.com?

```
#menu ul
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style:none;
}
```

This code makes me not seeing any dot in IE!

Comment: Hi,sorry, here it is: http://pastebin.com/Zrus1kKP I've had to remove the buttons just incase I get in trouble at work! :S

Comment: some css would also be nice :D

Comment: sorry, that xmas time is making me crazy!! Here's the CSS: http://pastebin.com/j2PgBTsb

Comment: Adding #menu ul
{
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-weight:bold;
 list-style:none;
} makes me not seeing dots in IE anymore.

Comment: Tried it and it worked nicely! Thank you kind Sir and have a Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```